# Cherrypy Post command increments mysql auto increment but does not insert into the database

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, cherrypy

I am working on my first web app, and I am running into a problem with mysql. I try to insert into my mysql database using the below POST function. What happens is that in my applied table, the auto increment value is incremented but nothing is inserted into the table. I am able to insert into the table in my ec2 instance using:

```
insert into applied (jobID, appID) values (1,8);
```

for example.

```
def POST(self, empID, jobID):
    print "jobID",jobID
    output_format = cherrypy.lib.cptools.accept(['application/json'])
    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=self.db['user'],
            host=self.db['host'],
            database=self.db['name'],
        )
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

    except Error as e:
        print e

    appID = 1
    qn="insert into applied (jobID, appID) values (%s,%s);" % (jobID, appID)
    try:
        cursor.execute(qn)
        cnx.close()
    except Error as e:
        print e
    print qn
    # Validate form data
    # Insert or update restaurant
    # Prepare response
    result = {}
    result['jobID'] = jobID
    result['appID'] = appID
    result['request'] = qn
    return json.dumps(result)
```

The mysql code that generates the database is:

```
CREATE TABLE `applied` (
  `appliedID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jobID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `appID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appliedID`),
  KEY `jobID` (`jobID`),
  KEY `appID` (`appID`),
  CONSTRAINT `applied_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`jobID`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`jobID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `applied_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`appID`) REFERENCES `applicants` (`appID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Don's string compound variables received from the your request into the statement. Put %s into your query string.  Add the arguments to the second argument in the execute statement, eg `cursor.execute(qn, [jobID, appID])`.  Or else get hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit the insert.  try this...

```
try:
    cursor.execute(qn)
    cursor.commit()
    cnx.close()
except Error as e:
```

Hope this helps!